# how to type in TypeScript npm code for package `pg`

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typescript-types

I am writing a Node (server-side only) application in TypeScript. I need to access a database and I am using the `pg` npm module. Where and how do I find the types I can use with it?
Currently my code is full of `any`:

```
pool.connect()
.then( (client: any) => {
  return client
   .query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1', [1])
   .then( (res: any) => {
   ...
```

You get the idea. I have both `@types/node` and `@types/pg` as development dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/node": "^18.0.3",
   "@types/pg": "^8.6.5",
```

... it is not clear to me whether I need both of them or not. My point is, how do I discover the types I can use? Do I read the code at `node_modules/@types/pg/index.d.ts` or is there a better way?

Comment: Do not add a type and let TypeScript automatically infer it. Then you can hover over the variable `client` or `res` and it will show you the type.

Comment: Here: https://tsplay.dev/WJydrm. Hover over `client` and `res`

Comment: @TobiasS. thanks but I'm on Emacs

Comment: Can you use await/async instead of promises and what would change in the code above?